# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (buf.data && buf.isContinuous()) in cv::imdecode_, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\loadsave.cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, curl

I am trying to load an image from an url using opencv and curl in visual studio 2010.While running the code I am getting the above mentioned error.What does that error mean?How can I correct my code.
Here is my code

```css
#include "curl/curl.h" // has to go before opencv headers

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

//curl writefunction to be passed as a parameter
// we can't ever expect to get the whole image in one piece,
// every router / hub is entitled to fragment it into parts
// (like 1-8k at a time),
// so insert the part at the end of our stream.
size_t write_data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    vector<uchar> *stream = (vector<uchar>*)userdata;
    size_t count = size * nmemb;
    stream->insert(stream->end(), ptr, ptr + count);
    return count;
}

//function to retrieve the image as cv::Mat data type
cv::Mat curlImg(const char *img_url, int timeout=10)
{
    vector<uchar> stream;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, img_url); //the img url
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data); // pass the writefunction
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &stream); // pass the stream ptr to the writefunction
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout); // timeout if curl_easy hangs, 
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl); // start curl
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl); // cleanup
    return imdecode(stream, -1); // 'keep-as-is'
}

int main(void)
{
    Mat image = curlImg("http://pimg.tradeindia.com/01063301/b/1/CRO-Oscilloscope.jpg");
 //   if (image.empty())
 //       return -1; // load fail

    namedWindow( "Image output", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    if (!image.empty())
  imshow("Image output",image); // here's your car ;)
    waitKey(0); // infinite
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This error relates to the size of stream passed to opencv imdecode(). Try to check the size of stream and see if its correct i.e. non-zero or non-null.